# Why libraries from Google require activity as a param?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Google has updated Firestore Auth library https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v20-0-0 and now `activity` is required to create `PhoneAuthOptions` which was not the case before.

Any ideas behind rationale of this change?

Comment: They want to listen to lifecycle events.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in the API documentation for [setActivity()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#setActivity(android.app.Activity)):

> Sets the Activity to which the callbacks are scoped, and with which app verification will be completed. This is a required parameter of the builder.

So, it's required to continue app verification after it's initiated.

I suggest also reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) to better understand why the activity is important here.  (By my understanding, the reliably resume the UI in the face of configuration changes.)

If you have to have a discussion with Firebase engineers about this, I suggest posting to [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk).